Show that the expression defines a norm
Let us consider the real vector space $V := C([-1, 1])$. Show that the expression $|| f || := max_{x ∈ [-1,1]}abs(\frac{1}{2}f(x))$ (for any $f ∈ V$) defines a norm on $V$.
To show that the expression defines a norm on the real vector space $C$ we need to verify that it satisfies the three properties of a norm:

Positivity;
Homogeneity;
Triangle Inequality.

Positivity
First, we need to show that $||f|| \geq 0$:
$||f|| = \max_{x \in [-1,1]} | \frac{1}{2} f(x) |$
Since the absolute value is always non-negative, $| \frac{1}{2} f(x) | \geq 0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$. Therefore, the maximum of a non-negative function is also non-negative:
$||f|| \geq 0$
Next, we need to show that $||f|| = 0$ if and only if $f = 0$:
$||f|| = 0 \implies \max_{x \in [-1,1]} | \frac{1}{2} f(x) | = 0$
This implies that $| \frac{1}{2} f(x) | = 0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$. Since $| \frac{1}{2} f(x)| = 0$ if and only if $f(x) = 0$, it follows that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$, hence $f = 0$.
Homogeneity
Next, we need to show that $||\alpha f|| = |\alpha| ||f\||$ for any scalar $\alpha$:
$||\alpha f|| = \max_{x \in [-1,1]}| \frac{1}{2} (\alpha f(x))|=$
$= \max_{x \in [-1,1]} | \alpha \cdot \frac{1}{2} f(x) |$
$= \max_{x \in [-1,1]} | \alpha| \cdot \frac{1}{2} f(x) |$
The question 1 is why could I take out $|\alpha|$ from the maximum???
$= |\alpha| \max_{x \in [-1,1]} | \frac{1}{2} f(x)|$
$= |\alpha| ||f||$
Thus, homogeneity is satisfied.
Triangle Inequality
Finally, we need to show that $||f + g|| \leq ||f|| + ||g||$:
$||f + g|| = \max_{x \in [-1,1]}| \frac{1}{2} (f(x) + g(x))|$
Using the triangle inequality for absolute values, we have:
$| \frac{1}{2} (f(x) + g(x))| \leq | \frac{1}{2} f(x)| + | \frac{1}{2} g(x)|$
Taking the maximum over $x \in [-1,1]$, we get:
$\max_{x \in [-1,1]} | \frac{1}{2} (f(x) + g(x))| \leq \max_{x \in [-1,1]}|\frac{1}{2} f(x) + \frac{1}{2} g(x) |$
The question 2 is why the maximum of two absolute values is less or equal the sum of maxima???
$\leq\max_{x \in [-1,1]}|\frac{1}{2} f(x)| + \max_{x \in [-1,1]}| \frac{1}{2} g(x) |$
Therefore,$||f + g|| \leq ||f|| + ||g||$. Thus, the triangle inequality is satisfied.

Answer for question 1:
We are trying to find $$\max _{x \in [-1,1]} |\alpha| \cdot \bigg|\frac{1}{2}f(x) \bigg|.$$
That $|\alpha|$ has nothing to do with $\max$ since we are taking $\max$ with respect to $x \in [-1,1].$
Answer to Question 2:
The proof for this directly follows from the proof for the triangle inequality for the normed space $C[-1,1]$ with the sup-norm, which is almost same as the norm that is given in the question except for it does not have a scalar factor of $\frac{1}{2}.$
